# How to export a lot of routes in a shpfile from OSMNX

Tags: python, python-3.x, osmnx

I have a trip data including lat,lng. I want to simulate the shortest paths of the trip,and export the paths to shpfile.Then I'll do the Linedensity Analysis to discover changes in the trips. I don't know how to export the paths as a shpfile
in once.
my sample data is below.you can save as station.csv

{
ride_id rideable_type   started_at  ended_at    start_station_name  start_station_id    end_station_name    end_station_id  start_lat   start_lng   end_lat end_lng member_casual
A847FADBBC638E45    docked_bike 2020/4/26 17:45 2020/4/26 18:12 Eckhart Park    86  Lincoln Ave & Diversey Pkwy 152 41.8964 -87.661 41.9322 -87.6586    member
5405B80E996FF60D    docked_bike 2020/4/17 17:08 2020/4/17 17:17 Drake Ave & Fullerton Ave   503 Kosciuszko Park 499 41.9244 -87.7154    41.9306 -87.7238    member
5DD24A79A4E006F4    docked_bike 2020/4/1 17:54  2020/4/1 18:08  McClurg Ct & Erie St    142 Indiana Ave & Roosevelt Rd  255 41.8945 -87.6179    41.8679 -87.623 member
2A59BBDF5CDBA725    docked_bike 2020/4/7 12:50  2020/4/7 13:02  California Ave & Division St    216 Wood St & Augusta Blvd  657 41.903  -87.6975    41.8992 -87.6722    member
27AD306C119C6158    docked_bike 2020/4/18 10:22 2020/4/18 11:15 Rush St & Hubbard St    125 Sheridan Rd & Lawrence Ave  323 41.8902 -87.6262    41.9695 -87.6547    casual
356216E875132F61    docked_bike 2020/4/30 17:55 2020/4/30 18:01 Mies van der Rohe Way & Chicago Ave 173 Streeter Dr & Grand Ave 35  41.8969 -87.6217    41.8923 -87.612 member
A2759CB06A81F2BC    docked_bike 2020/4/2 14:47  2020/4/2 14:52  Streeter Dr & Grand Ave 35  Fairbanks St & Superior St  635 41.8923 -87.612 41.8957 -87.6201    member
FC8BC2E2D54F35ED    docked_bike 2020/4/7 12:22  2020/4/7 13:38  Ogden Ave & Roosevelt Rd    434 Western Ave & Congress Pkwy 382 41.8665 -87.6847    41.8747 -87.6864    casual
9EC5648678DE06E6    docked_bike 2020/4/15 10:30 2020/4/15 10:35 LaSalle Dr & Huron St   627 Larrabee St & Division St   359 41.8949 -87.6323    41.9035 -87.6434    casual
}

This is my code(only get the picture of the path):

```
 `
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiLineString

ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)
# get a graph for some city
startlat = []
startlng = []
endlat = []
endlng = []
data = pd.read_csv("station.csv")
startlat = data['start_lat']
startlng = data['start_lng']
endlat = data['end_lat']
endlng = data['end_lng']

G2 = ox.graph_from_place('Chicago, Illinois', network_type='drive')
route_list = []
# get nodes and edges
nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G2, nodes=True, edges=True)

for i in range(len(startlng)):
    origin = (startlat[i], startlng[i])
    destination = (endlat[i], endlng[i])
    origin_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G2, origin)
    destination_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G2, destination)


    # exception handling, skipping points without path
    try:
        route = nx.shortest_path(G2, origin_node, destination_node, )
        route_nodes = nodes.loc[route]
        # Create a geometry for the shortest path
        route_line = MultiLineString(list(route_nodes.geometry.values))
        # Create a GeoDataFrame
        route_geom = gpd.GeoDataFrame([[route_line]], geometry='geometry', crs=edges.crs, columns=['geometry'])

    except:
        pass
    route_list.append(route)
    

fig, ax = ox.plot_graph_routes(G2, route_list, node_size=0)
    `
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62179444/7321942 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54652521/7321942

Comment: I'm only able to save one route in once, I want to save all routes in once as a shpfile

Comment: Then add several rows to the geopandas geodataframe before saving it.

Comment: thx, i'll try it

Comment: Professor ,my code  didn't  work yet  ,can u show me ,where's my problem

Comment: I would suggest revising your question to show a minimal reproducible example of everything you've tried and isolating one specific question you have about the code.

Comment: My English is poor , hope you can understand my question

Comment: thank you sir, I solved my question